# How to pre-configure (configure defaults for new users) KDE?

Tags: configuration, kde, default

I'm trying to figure out how to configure KDE for new users. That is: setting up KDE and make these settings default for every user upon her first login. I know that there's `/etc/skel` but it's not working nicely because KDE writes user- and machine-specific stuff in its users configuration files and I want this to work for every user on every machine. Also modifying stuff in `/usr/share` seems wrong to me as well as stuff there could get overwritten by an update or - even worse - modifications there could make auto upgrade fail.

So, is there a standard way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can always go the "*long way*". Create a dummy user, login into kde, configure it as you like and then:

1. Copy the entire ~/.kde (or ~/.kde4, I don't have access to a KDE machine now to check) 
   directory to a common place;
2. When you add a user to the system, copy in its home the .kde dir you previously saved;
3. When you are confident it works, make a script to do it automatically.

**EDIT**

As per comment below i've already done this in the past, both across users and machines. IIRC was one of the early KDE 4.X releases, it's been a while so maybe something have changed. It even worked for application specific configurations like amarok and kopete.
To be honest, I never tried the `/etc/skel` thing (which I know it's there for this exact reason, to have a default set of `dotfiles` for new user accounts) but maybe (don't really know!) doesn't work too good with directory trees? Manually copying the .kde dir has worked for me, though.

Comment: Well that's the same as writing it to /etc/skel, surely, and the OP already said that didn't work nicely ... (user/machine names in config keys?) Maybe it'd work if you made the script to search and replace all the problem strings?

Comment: @ams well i think so, but in the last two years I copied my .kde(4) dir to various machines and different accounts without any trouble.